# pointer being freed was not allocated (suspected due to double deletion)

Tags: c++, qt

Every time I try to delete an object in my array of pointers plantLayout[][], I get the error "pointer being freed was not allocated". I debugged it and realized that every time that I step into the ~Plant() destructor it goes into the malloc files and then back to the ~Plant() destructor, and then back into the malloc files, and then it gets that error. I am assuming that it is because of a double deletion error, but I can not seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

Below is the relevant code:

MainWindow.h: (relevant code)

```
const static int rows = 5;
const static int columns = 10;
Plant *plantLayout[rows][columns-1];
Plant *seedingPlant;
```

Plant.h

```
#ifndef PLANT_H
#define PLANT_H
#include <QString>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <sun.h>

class Plant
{ 
public:
    Plant();
    int x, y;//top left corner of the plant's lawn piece
    int width, height;//of lawn piece
    int plant, cost, life, range, damage, splash, slow, bomb, sun, need, row, column;
    static int statCost;
    double rate, seeding;
    QString name;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *icon;
    QString file;
    Sun sunObject;
    bool active;

    virtual void beginAttackingSequence();
    virtual void explosion();

};

#endif // PLANT_H
```

Plant.cpp

```
Plant::Plant()
{
    this->sun = 0;
    this->active = false;
    this->height = 60;
    this->width = 60;
    this->sunObject.onScreen = false;
}

void Plant::beginAttackingSequence(){

}

void Plant::explosion(){

}
```

I assign the set the seeding plant equal to a new SunFlower() which is a subclass of Plant

```
seedingPlant = new SunFlower();
```

and then later on I assign a certain element of the plantLayout[][] array to the seedingPlant.

```
plantLayout[r][c] = seedingPlant;
```

at later points in the program I reinitialize the seedingPlant to be another different subclass of the Plant.

```
if(plantLayout[r][c] != NULL){
    delete plantLayout[r][c];
}
```

I checked if that element is equal to null, which is what lead me to believe that it was a double delete that was causing the error!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: All this talk aout `Plant` destructor and no such shown.

Comment: Is `Plant *plantLayout[rows][columns-1];` a member of a class, or a global variable, or a local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have all of the code posted, but a few things I can suggest:

1. You mentioned that `SunFlower` is a subclass of `Plant`.  If you have polymorphic inheritance, you always want to have a virtual destructor (see [C++ FAQ 20.7](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-dtors.html) for more info).  In your case, add the following to the `Plant` declaration:

   ```
   virtual ~Plant();
   ```

   and add an implementation for it in Plant.cpp:

   ```
   Plant::~Plant()
   {
   }
   ```
2. You're checking for `NULL` before invoking `delete`.  You do not need to do that (and it's considered bad style).  `delete plantLayout[r][c];` by itself is just fine.  See [C++ FAQ 16.8](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/delete-handles-null.html) for more info.
3. Ensure that `plantLayout` is initialized to 0.  e.g., in the constructor for `MainWindow`, you'll probably want:

   ```
   for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
     for (int c = 0; c < columns-1; ++c)
       plantLayout[r][c] = NULL;
   ```

   My suspicion is that the "pointer being freed was not allocated" error is due to you invoking `delete plantLayout[r][c]` when `plantLayout[r][c]` is uninitialized (so it may contain some seemingly random value).